# Increment number and apply it to tableView header - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

I have made a table view inside a view controller. The table view also has headers and when clicked on them you can open and close each section.

I want to add a different title in each sections header with the first one being 01, second being 02 and so on.

I have tried getting the count number of the section and making that the title. However, it just makes every single title the same number. I don't know how to increment up from 01 and apply it to each section?

Any help would be amazing, thank you in advance.

I have a two dimensional array which looks like this:

```
    var twoDimensionalArray = [
        shootDaysExpandableNames(isExpanded: true, shotNumber: ["Cell_001", "Cell_002", "Cell_015"]),
        shootDaysExpandableNames(isExpanded: true, shotNumber: ["Cell_004", "Cell_006", "Cell_008", "Cell_010", "Cell_014"]),
        shootDaysExpandableNames(isExpanded: true, shotNumber: ["Cell_0017", "Cell_009", "Cell_020", "Cell_024", "Cell_34"])
    ]
```

And then I have my viewForHeaderInSection that looks like this:

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {

        let shotNumberInt = twoDimensionalArray[section].shotNumber.count
        let shootDayInt = twoDimensionalArray.count
        var shotNumberAmount = String(shotNumberInt) + (" Shots")
        var shootDay = String(shootDayInt)

        let line: UIView = {
            let line = UIView()
            line.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:0.63, green:0.63, blue:0.63, alpha:1.0)
            line.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            return line
        }()
        let openClose: UILabel = {
            let openClose = UILabel()
            openClose.text = "Open"
            openClose.textColor = UIColor(red:0.17, green:0.59, blue:0.30, alpha:1.0)
            openClose.font = UIFont(name: "Avenir-Medium", size: 12.0)
            openClose.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            return openClose
        }()

        let shootDayNumber: UILabel = {
            let shootDayNumber = UILabel()
            shootDayNumber.text = shootDay
            shootDayNumber.textColor = UIColor(red:0.18, green:0.20, blue:0.21, alpha:1.0)
            shootDayNumber.font = UIFont(name: "AvenirNext-Bold", size: 40.0)
            shootDayNumber.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

            return shootDayNumber
        }()

        let shootDate: UILabel = {
            let shootDate = UILabel()
            shootDate.text = shotNumberAmount
            shootDate.textColor = UIColor(red:0.63, green:0.63, blue:0.63, alpha:1.0)
            shootDate.font = UIFont(name: "Avenir-Medium", size: 12.0)
            shootDate.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            return shootDate
        }()

        let button = UIButton(type: .system)
            button.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
            button.addSubview(line)
            button.addSubview(shootDayNumber)
            button.addSubview(openClose)
            button.addSubview(shootDate)
            button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(HandleOpenClose), for: .touchUpInside)
            button.tag = section

        // CONSTRAINTS

        shootDayNumber.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: button.centerYAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        shootDayNumber.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: button.leftAnchor, constant: 17).isActive = true

        line.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: button.topAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
        line.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: shootDayNumber.rightAnchor, constant: 5).isActive = true
        line.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: button.rightAnchor).isActive = true
        line.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 1).isActive = true

        shootDate.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: button.bottomAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true
        shootDate.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: shootDayNumber.rightAnchor, constant: 5).isActive = true

        openClose.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: button.bottomAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true
        openClose.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: button.rightAnchor, constant: -17).isActive = true

        return button

    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {

        let shotNumberInt = twoDimensionalArray[section].shotNumber.count
        let shootDayInt = twoDimensionalArray.count

        var shotNumberAmount = String(shotNumberInt) + (" Shots")
        var shootDay = String(shootDayInt)

        let line: UIView = {
            let line = UIView()
            line.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:0.63, green:0.63, blue:0.63, alpha:1.0)
            line.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            return line
        }()

        let shootDayNumber: UILabel = {
            let shootDayNumber = UILabel()
            shootDayNumber.text = shootDay
            shootDayNumber.textColor = UIColor(red:0.18, green:0.20, blue:0.21, alpha:1.0)
            shootDayNumber.font = UIFont(name: "AvenirNext-Bold", size: 40.0)
            shootDayNumber.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

            return shootDayNumber
        }()

        let shotCount: UILabel = {
            let shotCount = UILabel()
            shotCount.text = shotNumberAmount
            shotCount.textColor = UIColor(red:0.63, green:0.63, blue:0.63, alpha:1.0)
            shotCount.font = UIFont(name: "Avenir-Medium", size: 12.0)
            shotCount.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            return shotCount
        }()

        let button = UIButton(type: .system)
            button.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
            button.addSubview(line)
            button.addSubview(shootDayNumber)
            button.addSubview(shotCount)
            button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(HandleOpenClose), for: .touchUpInside)
            button.tag = section

        // CONSTRAINTS

        shootDayNumber.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: button.centerYAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        shootDayNumber.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: button.leftAnchor, constant: 17).isActive = true

        line.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: button.topAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
        line.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: shootDayNumber.rightAnchor, constant: 5).isActive = true
        line.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: button.rightAnchor).isActive = true
        line.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 1).isActive = true

        openClose.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: button.bottomAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true
        openClose.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: button.rightAnchor, constant: -17).isActive = true

        return button
```

FYI: I am also adding a few other UILabels, UIImages to each header (these will be the same in each header), but I couldn't find a way to add them to each header without creating and giving constraints inside the viewForHeaderInSection function. Not sure if this the right way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
let shootDayInt = twoDimensionalArray.count
```

Is wrong. It should be

```
let shootDayInt = section + 1
```

(The count of elements in your twoDimensionalArray doesn't change, but the section number passed into your `tableView(_:viewForHeaderInSection:)` **does** change.)